# validation for entering only numbers in dynamically generated textboxes through javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table>
   <tbody id="add_weight">
      <tr></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<a onClick="edit_weights()" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><span   style="cursor:pointer; font-size:10px;">+Add more Weights.</span></a><br/><br/>
```

on page load there is no textbox but when i click on anchor tag a textbox opens for that i have applied a function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var b=1;
    function edit_weights() {
        if (b==10) {
            alert("can't Add more than 10 Weight Rates");
            return false;
        }

        var table=document.getElementById("add_weight");
        var row=table.insertRow(b);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);

        cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='edit_weight_from"+b+"' name='edit_weight_from"+b+"' style='width:100px; height:22px; float:left; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;'/>";

        b=b+1;
     }

</script>
```

now everytime i click on anchor tag a new textbox comes...now what i want is that when i try to enter alphabet in this textbox it should not take it .and when i enter number then it should take it so is there any way to do it??

Comment: 2 questions. You're using plain javascript only, no jQuery/Underscore or similar libraries? And by 'validation' you mean you want to block user input if he enters non-numbers?

Comment: yes sir...i want to block user input if he enters non_numbers...how can i achieve it...??

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: what that means...how can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

[It doesn't have the best browser support yet (IE<10)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number), but with HTML5, [we have many new input `types`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/). One is `<input type="number">` which will allow *only* numeric input.

In unsupported browsers it just defaults to a plain textbox (no validation). Combined with server-side validation, for some projects I can justify no JS validation on such fields for old internet explorer users. Perhaps you can to?

Comment: by applying this it is taking alphabat format also which i dont want...any other way